# on blur of input field validate field and cancel blur event if not valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am validating a field on blur event, and if the field is invalid I want the focus to remain in same field and not go to next field. When I do `$(this).focus()` within my blur function it only works in Chrome and not in Firefox. I tried the `settimeout` function but the problem is that the focus goes to next field (`#myInput2`) and then comes back to field (`#myInput1`). I don't want that as the next field also raises error cause it will be blurred again and it is empty. Is there a way to solve this in Firefox?

My code:

```
$('#myInput1').blur(function () {
    if (!validField1($(this).val())) {
        alert("Invalid");
        $(this).focus(); // Does not work in FF 
    }
});


$('#myInput2').blur(function () {
    if (!validField2($(this).val())) {
        alert("Invalid");
        $(this).focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: just a side note,`$('myInput2')` isnt a selector

Comment: Well it _is_ a selector – but since it would select elements with the _tag name_ `myInput2` it’s not gonna find much in an HTML document ;-)

Comment: In combination with the setTimeout approach, you could try disabling the following input fields (beforehand, when the current field receives focus) – so that they can’t receive focus.

Answer (score 0):

I asked this question once, these are generally browser features which is not lock down a user to one input box. User should have choice of going away if they wanted, whether or not it is valid.

So, Focus the same element after the blur event is disallowed.

**Edit:**

It seems chrome browser allows such effect such behavior but firefox and internet explorer does not.

Comment: Browser inconsistencies! But, you should avoid locking focus to an element at all costs.